# Number of balls in a slot

Tags: probability-theory

Let $N$  balls  are  distributed  among  $r$  cells  at  random, each  cell  being  free  to  receive  any  number  of balls.  Calculate  the  probability  that  a  particular cell  contains  k  balls  ($k\le N$)  when  $a$)  balls  are distinguishable, $b$) non-distinguishable. 
For the first part i think the answer is $Bin (N,\frac {1}{r})$
But for the second i dont know.please help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the probability model we use, and that is dictated by the physical situation.

But if balls are thrown one at a time towards the cells, with all cells equally likely to get the ball, and we have independence, then indistinguishable makes no difference to the probability. So for the second as for the first the probability is $\binom{N}{k}(1/r)^k (1-1/r)^{N-k}$.

Comment: Thnx.can you just help me find out when indistinguishable will play a difference.on which type of situation do i differentiate between them.?

Comment: There are some strange situations in quantum theory where if we do the analogue of flipping two coins, two heads, two tails, and one of each are equally likely.  If we were told explicitly that all the $\binom{N+r-1}{N}$ "Stars and Bars" possibilities are equally likely, that would change the probability calculation.